# Show and hide div seamlessly on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i hover over an item in a list of items and the hidden div belonging to that particular item will show when mouseover and disappear when mouseout? The current problem i have with this script is that only the first item fadein & out but when i hover over other items in the list, the first item is still the only target that fadein & out. pls help thanks in advance..

my script:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".title").hover(function(){
                $("#projdesc").fadeIn();
            }, function(){
               $("#projdesc").fadeOut();
            });

    });

         </script>
```

my html:

```
                    {% for job in job_list %}
                    {% if job.is_active %}
                    <tr class="{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}oddRow{% else %}evenRow{% endif %}">
                        <td width="40%">
                        <a href="{{ job.get_absolute_url }}">
                            <div class="title">
                                {{ job.title }} 
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div id="projdesc" class="proj_desc">
                            {{ job.description|truncatewords:28 }}
                        </div>
                        <td width="11%" valign="top">
                            <div class="posted_by">
                                {{ job.job_creator.nickname }}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="17%" valign="top">
                            <div class="proj_cat">
                                {{ job.skill.name }}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="8%" valign="top">
                            <div class="weekly_rate">
                                {{ job.budget|floatformat:0 }}
                            </div>
                            <td width="10%" valign="top">
                                <div class="proj_pDate">
                                    {{ job.created_at|date:"j/m/Y" }}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="7%" valign="top">
                                <div class="proj_LDate">
                                    {{ job.get_bid_time_left }}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="7%" valign="top">
                                <div class="bids">
                                    {{ job.get_no_of_bids }}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </td>
                        </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the description in a relative way. Here's one option:

```
$('.title').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.proj_desc').fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.proj_desc').fadeOut();
});
```

Also, as a side note, your HTML does not appear to be valid. That probably is *not* causing this problem, **but it will need to be fixed before this solution will work**. In particular, your first `td` does not have a closing tag before the next `td`, you have nested `td` tags, there appears to be a stray `</div>` tag just before the `</tr>`, and your `endif` and `endfor` should be outside of the `tr`.

Comment: now it work, it was due to an error from your typo earlier..the find('proj_desc') should be find('.proj_desc'). thanks for the quick response

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the typo in my original answer. For a deeper understanding, I recommend looking through all the functions at http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ There are actually a number of other good ways to solve your problem. One is by giving each hidden div a unique ID based on the ID stored in your database.

Answer (score 3):

You cant's have more than one element with the same id on a page. You need to make it a class. And to show the item belonging to this particalar element that you are hovering you need to do it like this

```
    $(".title").hover(function(){
            $(this).closest("tr").find(".projdesc").fadeIn();
        }, function(){
           $(this).closest("tr").find(".projdesc").fadeOut();
        });

});
```